# pytest- How to monkeypatch a function requiring 1+ arguments

Tags: python, pytest

I am learning **pytest** from the [official docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/monkeypatch.html) and found this example which suits my needs. I type in the following code, run **pytest** in file, and I get no failures:

```
import os.path

def getssh(): # pseudo application code
    return os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~admin"), '.ssh')

def test_mytest(monkeypatch):
    def mockreturn(path):
        return 'C:\\Users\\Admin\\'
    monkeypatch.setattr(os.path, 'expanduser', mockreturn)
    x = getssh()
    assert x == "C:\\Users\\Admin\\.ssh"
```

But when I adopt the above code to work with my real app-code i.e.

```
import random

def _mkRandom(low_lim, high_lim):
    """ generates a random number between given limits
    NOTE: sometimes the random number generated is so low
    that even after multiplication it remains smaller than
    lower limit, this function tries to handle such cases also.
    """
    x = random.random()
    x = x*high_lim
    if x<low_lim:
        print("Special case encountered")
        x+= low_lim
    return x

def test_mkRandom(monkeypatch):
    def mockreturn(low, high):
        return 0.001
    monkeypatch.setattr(random, "random", mockreturn)
    x = _mkRandom(1, 2)
    assert x == 1.002
    return
```

I get the following error:

```
================================== FAILURES ===================================
________________________________ test_mkRandom ________________________________

monkeypatch = <_pytest.monkeypatch.MonkeyPatch object at 0x027DB330>

    def test_mkRandom(monkeypatch):
        def mockreturn(low, high):
                return 0.001
        monkeypatch.setattr(random, "random", mockreturn)
>       x = _mkRandom(1, 2)

monkey.py:22:
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

low_lim = 1, high_lim = 2

    def _mkRandom(low_lim, high_lim):
        """ generates a random number between given limits
        NOTE: sometimes the random number generated is so low
        that even after multiplication it remains smaller than
        lower limit, this function handles such cases also.
        """
>       x = random.random()
E    TypeError: mockreturn() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'low' and 'high'

monkey.py:11: TypeError
===================== 1 failed, 1 passed in 0.16 seconds ======================
```

How do I test `_mkRandom` properly?

Comment: 1. Is there a particular reason to build fake functions like that, rather than just set `return_value`? 2. You've patched  out `random.random` for a function that takes two parameters, but are calling it without any; what was the expected outcome?

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks for suggesting the `return_value` thing but I've got to teach this to non English speakers so I've got to stick with that style

Comment: You need to point your monkeypatch to `_mkRandom` instead of `random.random`. For testing functions that have some sort of randomization, I would suggest to use [seeding](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.seed) instead of monkeypatching.